# Magento 2 Grid value not changing on update for an attribute

Tags: magento-2.1, attributes

After changing value of a custom attribute in products , the change is not reflecting in the Grid but the change is getting reflected on the product edit page.

Comment: tried clearing the cache?

Comment: Run command php bin/magento indexer:reindex and check again

Comment: do caching and indexing, then check your grid.

Comment: Done , but no effect

Answer (score 0):

Setting the attribute scope to `Global` fixed the issue for me.